# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' when calling into Mongo's C# Driver on .NET Core

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm upgrading my web application from the .NET Framework version of ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core. I've worked through all of the C# and Razor build errors, and now I'm trying to run the application for the first time. When I make any calls into MongoDB's C# driver:

```
public static Analytics Find(Enums.Platform platform, DateTime date) {
            var builder = Filter;
            var filters = builder.Eq("Platform", platform) & builder.Eq("Date", date);
            return Collection().Find(filters).FirstOrDefault();// Exception thrown here.
        }
```

It errors:

> System.TypeLoadException   HResult=0x80131522   Message=Could not load
>   type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core
>   StackTrace:    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Events.EventContext.AsyncLocal`1.get_Value()    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Events.EventContext.BeginOperation(Nullable`1
>   operationId)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindCommandOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.Execute(IReadBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IReadBinding
>   binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, IReadOperation`1 operation, ReadPreference readPreference,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteReadOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0`1.b__0(IClientSessionHandle
>   session)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1
>   filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
>   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.FirstOrDefault[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluentExtensions.FirstOrDefault[TDocument,TProjection](IFindFluent`2
>   find, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Housters.Data.DataAccess.AnalyticsData.Find(Platform platform,
>   DateTime date) in
>   C:\Housters\Data\DataAccess\Common\AnalyticsData.cs:line 22    at
>   Housters.Business.Services.Common.AnalyticsService.Get(Platform
>   platform, DateTime date) in
>   C:\Housters\Business\Services\Common\AnalyticsService.cs:line 31    at
>   Housters.Business.Services.Common.AnalyticsService.Log(Platform
>   platform, String deviceId, AnalyticsEventType type, Boolean
>   onlyLogIfSignedUp) in
>   C:\Housters\Business\Services\Common\AnalyticsService.cs:line 19    at
>   Housters.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in
>   C:\Housters\Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 8    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()

I'm confused as to what's going on because MongoDB supports .NET Core, and yet System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext is a .NET Framework method, .NET Core doesn't support it. I saw [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875412/how-can-i-use-the-mongodb-driver-with-c-sharp-asp-net-core-api-framework) where the OP was facing this issue, however his problem was that he wasn't using the latest MongoDB C# Driver. I'm using the latest driver, 2.8.0, within a .NET Standard (2.0.3) class library.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `MongoDb.Driver 2.9.0-beta1`

Comment: You 'Data' project is a '.NET Standard (2.0.3) class library' - right? What about your web project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nupkg is essentially a zip file with multiple versions of the DLL and some metadata.

In case of Mongo driver, there are DLLs for two target environments

- .NET Framework 4.5.2
- .NET Standard 1.5

When installing a NuGet package, the dll matching your project is selected. I assume you are still referencing .NET framework DLL, despite using a NuGet package that supports .NET Standard.

Try re-installing your NuGet package.
Verify that DLL that lands in your bin for matches .NET Standard version.